# Random Variable transformation problem

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I'm stuck with the following problem:

**Problem:**

If $X$ is a random variable defined as the sum of rolling a pair of dice, find the probability distribution of the remainder obtained when $X$ is divided by $3.$

**Thoughts**

Let say that $Y=$ the remainder obtained when $X$ is divided by 3

So $Y=X\bmod3$ which is defined as

$Y=X\bmod3=X-3\lfloor \frac{X}{3}\rfloor$ based on [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mod.html).

$Y=X-3\lfloor \frac{X}{3} \rfloor$

But honestly I'm pretty much stuck there, I'm not sure on how to represent the problem.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The number of values of $Y$ and $X$ is small enough that you can work it out directly.  For instance $P(Y=0) = P(X=3) + P(X=6) + P(X=9) + P(X=12)$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thanks. It was really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering a random variable:
\begin{eqnarray*}
    X:\Omega    & \to   &    \{2,3,\dots,12\}\\
      \omega    &\mapsto&    X(\omega) = n
\end{eqnarray*}
and
\begin{eqnarray*}
    Y:\Omega    & \to   &    \{0,1,2\}\\
      \omega    &\mapsto&    Y(\omega) = \frac{X(\omega)}{3}-\left[\frac{X(\omega)}{3}\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
where $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$. Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
    \mathbb{P}(Y=k)
    & = &    \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{X(\omega)}{3}-\left[\frac{X(\omega)}{3}\right]=k\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

But on the other hand, by total probability
\begin{eqnarray*}
    \mathbb{P}(Y=k)
    &=&    \sum_{n=2}^{12} \mathbb{P}(Y=k|X=n)\mathbb{P}(X=n)\\
\end{eqnarray*}

since you have a finite number of cases for $n$ and you know the distribution of $X$, then
\begin{eqnarray*}
    \mathbb{P}(Y=k)
    &=&    \sum_{n\in\{2,\dots,12\}\wedge k=0} \mathbb{P}(Y=k|X=n)\mathbb{P}(X=n)\\
    & &    +\sum_{n\in\{2,\dots,12\}\wedge k=1} \mathbb{P}(Y=k|X=n)\mathbb{P}(X=n)\\
    & &    +\sum_{n\in\{2,\dots,12\}\wedge k=2} \mathbb{P}(Y=k|X=n)\mathbb{P}(X=n)\\
\end{eqnarray*}

my notation is not very lucky, but the idea is to note that you can identify the elements $n$ that have remainder $0$,$1$ or $2$ as appropriate, since the probability over $Y$ will be equal taking advantage of the fact that $k$ is given from $n$.

Comment: I think that the OP makes reference to two dice.

Comment: Thanks, I just fixed it @AntoniParellada

Comment: Shouldn't $Y(\omega) = \frac{X(\omega)}{3}-\left[\frac{X(\omega)}{3}\right]$ be $Y(\omega) = X(\omega)-3\lfloor \frac{X(\omega)}{3}\rfloor$?

Comment: Yes!, that's why it mentions that $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$, is notation

Comment: @MATorres Thanks for taking the time to elaborate that rigorous answer, really educative.